# Is every $C^k$ embedding the restriction of a diffeomorphism on a subspace?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, inverse-function-theorem

Let $D$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\phi:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a $C^k$ embedding. Is $\phi$ the restriction of some diffeomorphism (on $\mathbb{R}^n$) on the subspace $\mathbb{R}^d \times \{(0,\dots,0)\}$?

Two remarks that are consequences of the inverse function theorem:

1. The statement is locally true.
2. For $d=n$ the statement is true.

Comment: If you take $\phi:(0,1)\to \Bbb R^2$, $\phi(t)=(\cot(\pi t),0)$, then you can't extend continuously $\phi$ to $\Bbb R$, and therefore there is no continuous $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ such that $g(t,0)=\phi(t)$ for all $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: This is not a counterexample. When I say diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^n$ I mean that its domain can be any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Ok, fine by me.

Comment: @Plemath When the normal bundle $N(\phi(D))$ is trivial, this looks to be a special case of the tubular neighborhood theorem.